# Finding all harmonic functions on $C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I can only come up with the following examples.
Suppose $x = (x_1,...,x_n)$.
0. $u = c$ constant.

1. $u = x_i$ is harmonic.
2. $u = x_i x_j$ is harmonic.
3. Any translation, rotation, reflection of the above example.
4. Any linear combination of the above.

I wonder if this characterize all harmonic functions in my domain? If so, why?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There’re probably a few others.

Comment: How do you define the Laplacian on the space of functions of functions with a continuous 2nd derivative?

Answer (score 1):

Harmonic functions are necessarily smooth, so the restriction to functions in $C^2(\mathbb R^n)$ is redundant.

This is certainly not every harmonic function, very far from it in fact. An example of a harmonic function that does not fit into your classification is
$$u(x,y) =\sin x \cosh y $$ which is harmonic in $\mathbb R^2$.

In fact, given any complex analytic function $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$, the real part is harmonic in $\mathbb R^2$ i.e. $u(x,y) := \operatorname{Re} (f(x+\mathrm{i}y) )$ is harmonic, so there are many many more harmonic functions than the ones you mention. (The above counter-example is the real part of $z \mapsto \sin z$ with $z=x+\mathrm iy$)

Comment: Thus it seems that  harmonic functions on $\mathbb R^2$ form an infinite dimensional vector space since it includes all poynomials in one complex variable.  Can we give to this space the structure of an Hilbert space or a Banach space?

Comment: Thank you. What about in the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$?